# how to find a column group by another column in a given date using mysql

Tags: mysql

How to select

```
   visiter_ip          page                 date                 page_views
   127.0.0.1           abc.php              12-7-2012                2
   214.21.45.1         daf.php              12-7-2012                1
   545.45.44.12        abc.php              12-7-2012                1
   214.21.45.1         abc.php              12-7-2012                1
   214.21.45.1         xyz.php              12-7-2012                1
```

"214.21.45.1" where date is Today and total page_views

**example**

```
         visiter_ip     =   page_views

         214.21.45.1     =      3             when date is 12-7-2012
```

Comment: Please ans with full query i am new to mysql

Comment: My answer below is probably not what you want. You should [show what you have tried](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/) and also show what your table looks like. Providing a couple of rows is enough. Then state **exactly** how the output should look like. Don't try to paraphrase it. Usually it's easier to just show what you have and what you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this Query:

```
SELECT visiter_ip AS visiter_ip, 
       SUM(page_views) AS page_views 
FROM <table_name> 
WHERE visiter_ip = '214.21.45.1' 
  AND date = CURDATE();
```

Let me know if it works or not.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is very unclear because it's not clear if you provide a table layout or example data. I'll try anyway.

```
SELECT visiter_ip, page, date, page_views FROM table WHERE visiter_ip = '214.21.45.1' and `date` = DATE(NOW()) ORDER BY page_views DESC;
```